# Check if a particular app is installed or launched on iOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Does anybody know how to check if a particular app is installed or launched on iOS 9.

Previously I used a PhoneGap plugin that returned a list of running apps so I could check it (using sysctrl). But it doesnt work on iOS 9 because they have closed many backdoors. It could be a list or just a check for a particular app (process or budle name or whatever else). As I understand ulrscheme is not working for this purpose, because this should work for any app, with or without urls setup.

App is designed for Enterprise Distribution model so we can use some hacks if needed because it`s not for App Store distribution and verification.

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible in iOS9. Check [this](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes) article.

Comment: I know that this is possible, I already have seen and tested apps that have this functionality. I dont know how do they do it, but I know this is possible.
I`m not sure if this is a list or just a one-app-check but it works for any app.

Comment: which apps? ask them how they do it

Comment: You can check the private frameworks. There is a framework called Symbolication.framework which contains some methods could get all apps installed on the device.